# Annotate datatime calculations

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

How could I cast datetime to seconds and perform calculation on that or directly perform calculation on datetime?

for example:

```
User.objects.annotate(min=Min('created'), max=Max('created'), perc=F('created') - min/(max - min))
```

User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How to get the value of `perc` for each user(I'm using postgres)?

Comment: How does the User model look like?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the annotation? What is your aim?